# Разметка сайта на CSS

Tags: html, css

Стыдно просить о таком, но мне нужна помощь в создании css для сайта. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы под заголовком было три столбца, но не получается и если я передвигаю один элемент, то смещаются все. Может кто-нибудь показать, как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: Ну вы сами прдумайте, откуда здесь кто то знает как вы это делали, не видно же ваш код, ваш заголовок с тремя столбцами, выложите сюда весь код

Comment: Иначе вопрос закроют так как не ясна суть вопроса

Comment: @MonkeyMutant как по мне, лучше закрыть по причине: `Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») ...`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 согласен..вроде бабушка Ванга давно у Господа..и гадать некогда